# Sending outlook company group mail using Google script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, outlook

```
function sendEmail(){
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet33");
        var range = sheet.getRange("A1:K");
        var tempSheet = ss.insertSheet(`sheet33_temp`);
        range.copyTo(tempSheet.getRange("A1"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
        range.copyTo(tempSheet.getRange("A1"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS, false);
        range.copyFormatToRange(tempSheet, 1, 1, 1, 1);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        var tempSheetId = tempSheet.getSheetId();
        var spreadsheetName = tempSheet.getSheetName();
        
        var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetId + "/export?format=xlsx&gid=" + tempSheetId ;
                
        // dd
        var date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        var dd = Utilities.formatDate(date , "GMT+9", "yyyyMMdd") ;
        
        
        var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token  
          },
          muteHttpExceptions: true   
        });

        
        var blobs = response.getBlob();
        blobs.setName(`${spreadsheetName}_${dd}.xlsx`)
        var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('123456asdfK');
        backupFile = folder.createFile(blobs);
                              
        
        var receipient = `grp_k@asdf.onmicrosoft.com`
        var subject = spreadsheetName + `_${dd} List Share.
        var message = spreadsheetName + `_${dd} List Share.
Thanks.`

        MailApp.sendEmail(receipient, subject, message, {attachments: blobs});
        
        Browser.msgBox(`${spreadsheetName}${dd} ${receipient} Send Complete.`, Browser.Buttons.OK);


        ss.deleteSheet(tempSheet); 
}
```

Using a script to talk about the day's deadline in the company
Copy the desired tab from the spreadsheet to a temp file, extract the desired range again, convert it to Excel, and upload it to Google Drive.
In addition, an e-mail is sent with Excel as an attachment.

The problem works fine if I test it by sending it to my personal email address within the company.
However, it should be sent and received to a specific Outlook mail "group" in which several people belong to the company, but the script works, but the mail is not received from the "group".

For the part that is not received from G-suit account to Outlook, I set Edit> Allow external mail reception in the group setting, but it is still not received.

When sending with a MailApp script, you cannot check the history in the mailbox sent to Outlook.
Received mail is also sent to G-suit account. I want to check Gmail history, but access is restricted due to company security policy.

**What you need help with**

1. How to send mail from Google Script to Outlook
   OR
2. How to send mail to the Outlook "group" used by the company

In fact, if it can be solved with number 1, I think there is a possibility that it will be solved because my account uses Outlook (MS account).

However, it is too difficult to solve with my insufficient skills, so I ask for help.

I searched all of the stack / developers, but
No corresponding conference was found.

I need help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your situation, is this Google Apps Script library useful? https://github.com/tanaikech/OnedriveApp I updated this to v1.2.0 for getting and sending emails using a Microsoft account. When this library is used, the email can be sent by own Microsoft account. So the sent email can be seen at Outlook. If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for answer.
I tried it through the OneDrive you suggested, but it's a pity that I can't use it because I don't have access rights in the company group. Thank you so much for your concern for me.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comment was not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `MailApp` documentation:

> Sends email.
>
> This service allows users to send emails with complete control over the content of the email. Unlike `GmailApp`, `MailApp`'s sole purpose is sending email. `MailApp` *cannot access a user's Gmail inbox*.

Therefore, if you want to send an email to an Outlook address using Apps Script, `MailApp` is the appropriate choice in this situation.

**As for receiving the email, you might want to double check the email address you inputted as well as the specific settings for the group.**

#### Reference

- [Apps Script MailApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app).

Comment: Obviously, Mailapp is a script that I know to send using the default mail app, but I wondered if it was correct because there was no history of sending the mail in the outbox history in Outlook.

Comment: Gmail is even more frustrating because it is not possible to check the shipping history because it does not have access rights due to internal regulations.
When sending personal e-mails automatically, I modified the script that I used well and created the script for the current company, but I am frustrated because I don't know how to work with Google vs. MS office.

Thank you for answering my question.

I'm thinking a lot until I get help with an exciting additional answer...

Comment: When I set up Gmail pop in Outlook and checked the sent mailbox, it was confirmed that it was sent to Outlook via Gmail account, not from Outlook.
I am thinking about whether there is a way to send using Outlook using a script.